# How to get first element from Value List of a Dictionary?

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following declaration and I need to get the first element from the list using key. Then after assigning that value to some variable again I need to remove that value alone from that list.

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> data = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
```

**For Example:**

```
List<string> teamMembers = new List<string>();
teamMembers.Add("Country1Player1");
teamMembers.Add("Country1Player2");
teamMembers.Add("Country1Player3");
data.Add("Country1",teamMembers);
teamMembers = new List<string>();
teamMembers.Add("Country2Player1");
teamMembers.Add("Country2Player2");
teamMembers.Add("Country2Player3");
data.Add("Country2",teamMembers);
```

From the above dictionary, I need to select the Country1 's first element Country1Player1 and assign to some variable. After that I need to remove that value alone from the value list.

**Expected output:**
If I pass key as 'Country1' then it should give me Country1Player1 and that value needs to be removed the data dictionary. Key Country1 should contain only Country1Player2 & Country1Player3 in the list of values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string firstTeamMember = null;
if (data.TryGetValue("Country1", out List<string> list) && list?.Any() == true)
{
    firstTeamMember = list[0];
    list.RemoveAt(0);
}
```

Comment: For adding the null conditional operator +1. I missed that one.

Comment: @Christos - Will removing the last item from the list throw any error?

Comment: @Christos - Actually I need to add new list of values to that key if existing list becomes empty.

Comment: @Ask_SO: No, what kind of error you are afraid of? Of course you can add to the code `if(!list.Any()) list.Add(somethingnew)`

Comment: @TimSchmelter - if possible could you please update answer to handle empty list scenario. I am not sure where to add this line if(!list.Any()) list.Add(somethingnew).

Comment: @Ask_SO: Right after this line: `list.RemoveAt(0);`. This is where the list could become empty

Answer (score 1):

You could try sth like this:

```
if(data.TryGetValue("Country1", out var values))
{
    var firstValue = values?.FirstOrDefault();
    data["Country1"] = data["Country1"]?.Skip(1).ToList();
}
```

Comment: @TimSchmelter I might misinterpreted sth. Doesn't `data["Country1"].Skip(1)` filter out the first item from the list and calling `ToList`, would perform that and you get back a list containing all elements but the first of the initial list. Isn't that OP wants ?